# Regex to replace first occurence only in perl

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy

I have a text file with these entries

```
data,34.45,5343

intaa,34353.5, 646463 
dedaa, 22542.35, 3564643
eerreg, 3435,335353

rtgegr,343543,34332
```

I want to replace the first empty line only and ignore any empty lines which are present in the file. how could i do this ?

I read about nongreedy in regex but couldn't find a proper match to my needs. Can someone suggest ?

My final data should look like this

```
data,34.45,5343
intaa,34353.5, 646463
dedaa, 22542.35, 3564643
eerreg, 3435, 335653

rtgegr,343543,34332
```

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of providing a "solution" rather than a "solution using regex", just condition on an empty line and a flag that tells whether you've removed an empty line or not.

Assuming one line in each element of `@input`,

```
@output = grep { /\S/ || !$flag++ } @input
```

will exclude the first line (and only the first line) that does not contain a non-whitespace character. You might prefer a solution like this because multi-line regular expressions require some extra care to get correct.

Answer (score 3):

Set a `$flag` in perl and verify if it is set in `if` under a loop:

```
perl -lne 'if((/^\s*$/ && !$flag)){$flag=1;next;}print' file
```

**Output:**

```
data,34.45,5343
intaa,34353.5, 646463 
dedaa, 22542.35, 3564643
eerreg, 3435,335353

rtgegr,343543,34332
```

Comment: Great minds think alike, and coincidentally, so do ours.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:
First line can also be an "empty line"
Multiple "empty lines" adjacent are not treated as one empty line. only the first empty line is removed.

How about something like `s/((\n)(\n)|(^\n)())/`

And replace the 1st capture group with nothing.

I am not 100% sure about the perl syntax since my perl days are long gone.

Comment: I just updated it, i think you need to replace it with a newline and not "nothing" like i wrote before. I am trying to craft an example and post it here.

Comment: Sorry, with the assumption that the first line CAN be an empty line i cannot easily solve it. Otherwise i can provide multiple solutions that work. Did my best though.

Comment: @Ashwin Now it seems to work on my test cases. You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/lQ8gO0/1)

Answer (score 0):

If empty line *can* be a line with horizontal whitespaces then this

`$str =~ s/(?m)^\h*\n//;`

If empty line *cannot* contain horizontal whitespaces then this

`$str =~ s/(?m)^\n//;`

Comment: Pretty simple really.

Comment: Why don't you put the `/m` modifier on the end of the substitution like the rest of the world?

Comment: @Borodin - Its self contained, unlike the rest of the world.

Comment: And how does that self-containment help anybody? Unfortunately the majority of your audience won't understand what you've written. I suspect it's more to do with display and pretentiousness than any advantage that self-containment can offer

Comment: @Borodin - Well, its easily cut from the Perl delimiters and deposited into Javas' without losing that important relationship `(?m)^`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read all of your file into memory, you can do this

```
s/^\h*\n//m
```

The `/m` (multiline) modifier allows `^` to match the beginning of any line in the file. `\h*` matches zero or more horizontal whitespace characters, and `\n` matches the newline at the end of the line

The substitution will find the first occurrence of the pattern and remove it